# Please update syntax coloring to support underscores in JavaScript number literals

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

```js
1000000
1_000_000
```

Both these literals are modern ways to represent the same number, but the syntax coloring stops at the underscore.

I hope this can be fixed.

Turns out the answer is:

> **Stack Exchange does not have its own syntax highlighting engine.** It uses [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/), and is not necessarily using the latest release of that library. Therefore, any bugs and feature requests regarding syntax highlighting cannot be handled by Stack Exchange.

Comment: This is supported in version 10.3 just released.  I do not know when SO will update to the latest version.